# C# use of new to instantiate an object

Tags: c#, class, object

From my experience of C++, I know that in C, objects declared as `ClassName ObjectName;` are stored on the stack, and objects declared as `ClassName ObjectName = new ClassName;` are stored on the heap.

In C#, I seem to be being told from everywhere that the `new` keyword must be used, i.e. you cannot initialize an object like `ClassName ObjectName;` i.e.

```
Product P;
P.someMethod();
```

Why is this?

Comment: Is `Product` a `class` or `struct`? If it is a class: does this work or does it throw an exception?

Comment: First thing you need to differentiate between is an *object* and a *variable*. Also note that while fields (instance/static variables) have default values (e.g. null for any reference type), local variables do not.

Comment: Are you sure that Product is not a struct?

Comment: @Pawel Reszka Structs also need to be initialized with new, am i right ?

Comment: No, they can be initialized automatically with default value. Like int will get 0 when nothing is assigned.

Comment: The best question! What IDE do you use? We are talking about struct / class but as far as i know visual studio is not the only one IDE guys

Comment: @PawełReszka try doing it in a method make a int variable without assigning it any value and try printing, You will see :-)

Comment: Thanks guys. It turned out the code did not actually compile, the "unassigned local variable" error was hidden by accident. A combination of mohits00691 and Jon Skeet's answers is what I was looking for, the part I was confused about is that even though p is declared as a type of Product, it has no default value and is not instantiated until it is set with "= new Product". Whereas in C++, Product P would instantiate the object of class Product.

Comment: C# compiler enforces this that no matter what, you need to assign a local variable, before using it.

Comment: Damn, I lied to you. Sorry for misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C# class Objects and any values in the objects will always be stored on the heap. The new key word allocates memory on the heap for the object and any values it has, and returns the reference to its location. Until this is done you should not be able to work with the object functions.

so in example:

```
Product P = new Product();
```

p is actually a reference to the allocated object. An object can have multiple references to the same object.

```
Product C = P;
```

In the case C does not copy P, but it copies the reference to the object.

Structs work differently than objects since they are allocated on the stack. This means the same operation as above will actually copy the struct and allocate new memory for it on the stack.

Comment: Maybe a bit incomplete, I don't see how copying a struct would result in allocating it on the heap. If `P` and `C` are variables (of value types), they are (in normal methods) allocated on the stack when the method is run. If they are fields of a class, they are allocated on the heap when the object that contains them is created. If the containing type is a structure, again, the structure could be in a variable or a field etc.

Comment: I made a typo at the end. Where it now says stack it used to say heap which is incorrect as structs are never allocated on the heap.

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer my own question for the sake of pulling the info together for clarity.

A combination of mohits00691 and Jon Skeet's answers clears this up. Even though P is declared as a type of Product, it has no default value and is not instantiated until it is set with "= new Product".

This differs from C++, where `Product P` would instantiate an object of class Product.

Answer (score -2):

as far i know, code like :

```
Product p;
p.someFunction();
```

will throw an error while compiling only : "Unassigned Local variable". So you need to give value to every variable, be it reference type or value type, before using it in C#.

Comment: This is incomplete in several different ways (see the comments).

Comment: @Jeroen Vannevel where am i wrong here ? please give an example ? i want to correct myself.

Comment: Thanks guys. It turned out the code did not actually compile, the "unassigned local variable" error was hidden by accident. A combination of mohits00691 and Jon Skeet's answers is what I was looking for, the part I was confused about is that even though p is declared as a type of Product, it has no default value and is not instantiated until it is set with "= new Product". Whereas in C++, Product P would instantiate the object of class Product.